# SSL connection to Db2 fails if using SSLClientKeystoredb and SSLClientKeystash keywords. C++

Tags: ssl, db2

I follow the instructions at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0053514.html

On server I created kdb storage with self-signed certificate:

```
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -keydb -create -db server.kdb -stash -genpw
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -create -db server.kdb -stashed -label server_cert -dn "CN=TestCompany"
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -extract -db server.kdb -stashed -label server_cert -target server_cert.arm -format ascii
```

Configured Db2 instance to use SSL:

```
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_SVR_KEYDB <full path to server.kdb>"
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_SVR_STASH <full path to server.sth>"
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_SVR_LABEL server_cert"
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_SVCENAME db2cs_DB2"
db2set -i <instance_name> DB2COMM=SSL
db2stop
db2start
```

On the client add server_cert.arm to the client storage

```
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -keydb -create -db client.kdb -stash -genpw
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -add -db client.kdb -stashed -label client_cert -file server_cert.arm -format ascii
```

On server I created database TDB and catalog it on the client machine:

```
db2 "CATALOG TCPIP NODE SSLNODE REMOTE ... SERVER ... SECURITY SSL"
db2 "CATALOG DB TDB AS TDBSSL AT NODE SSLNODE"
```

Setup SSL_CLNT_KEYDB and SSL_CLNT_STASH to test connection:

```
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_CLNT_KEYDB <full path to client.kdb>"
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_CLNT_STASH <full path to client.sth>"
db2stop
db2start
```

And `db2 connect to TDBSSL user ... using ...` works.

Return client instance configuration to its original state

```
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_CLNT_KEYDB NULL"
db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING SSL_CLNT_STASH NULL"
db2stop
db2start
```

Next I am trying connect to the TDBSSL from C++ code.
If I use connection string like `DSN=TDBSSL;UID=...;PWD=...;Security=ssl;SSLServerCertificate=<full path to server_cert.arm>"` , connection is estableshed

But if I use SSLClientKeystoredb and SSLClientKeystash keywords
`DSN=TDBSSL;UID=...;PWD=...;Security=ssl;SSLClientKeystoredb=<full path to client.kdb>;SSLClientKeystash=<full path to client.sth>;` ,
connection fails with error

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "SSL".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "".  Communication function detecting the error: "sqlccSSLSocketSetup".  Protocol specific error code(s): "414", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

Maybe I missed something and the second connection string is wrong or should contain some additional keywords?

Client db2level

```
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11013" with level identifier
"0204010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.3030.239", "s1803021700",
"DYN1803021700WIN64", and Fix Pack "3".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1"
```

Server db2level

```
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "d111a1")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11014" with level identifier
"0205010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.4.4", "s1808090100", "DYN1808090100AMD64",
and Fix Pack "4".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1_01".
```

Comment: Yes. Client and server on different machines. Client on Windows, server on Linux. Also add server db2level

Comment: When the client side SSL_CLNT_KEYDB and SSL_CNLT_STASH parameters are correctly set, you write that the CLP connect succeeds, but does the C++ code work in this specific case  ?  (you write that the C++ code fails when these parms are NULL but connection-attributes give suitable values).

Comment: Yes. When the SSL_CLNT_KEYDB and SSL_CNLT_STASH parameters are set, C++ code works with the  SSLClientKeystoredb and SSLClientKeystash keywords

Comment: Please try additional keyword "SSLClientLabel=...;"  (taking care to match the value with the label you've given to the cert in the keystore).

Comment: With SSLClientLabel keyword, I get [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0222E  Authentication failed because the SSLClientLabel parameter was specified but the DB2 client or data server driver was not configured to use certificate-based authentication. SQLSTATE=HY000

Comment: OK, sorry about that. The 414 code means bad certificate.  Have you tried `-default_cert yes` when adding the server-cert to the client keystore? (It is deprecated, but should still work)

Comment: I don't see option -default_cert in command `gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -add`, so I used command `gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -setdefault`. Same 414 error. Just a note, command `gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -list -db client.kdb -stashed` shows `!       client_cert`

Comment: possible defect. If you want to debug further, then compare the client side `db2trc` formatted output between the working and failing cases (i.e. both SSL_CLNT_KEYDB/STASH set to NULL versus set to valid valies) . Do you have a Db2 support contract or Enterprise Agreement?

Comment: Yes I do. I will debug more with db2trc. Maybe see something in db2diag.log. I will add comment if something clears up. Thanks for the help